# Cache duplicate Universal ImageLoader and Picasso

Tags: android, caching, picasso, universal-image-loader

Use two biblotecas in my application, Universal Image Loader and another that uses the library picasso,

the picasso library, records the image in the cache /cache/picasso-cache/ and the names are generated with the MD5 URL.

To separate the cache Universal Image Loader, I write to /cache/LazyLoad/ and names generated with the item ID.

My code of configuration Universal Image Loader

```
DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
                .cacheOnDisk(true)
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
                .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300))
                .build();

ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder config = new  ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext());
        config.defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions);
        config.memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache());
        config.threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2);
        config.denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory();

        config.tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO);
        config.writeDebugLogs(); // for debug

FileNameGenerator fileNameGenerator = new FileNameGenerator() {
            @Override
            public String generate(String imageUri) {
                String fileName = imageUri.substring(imageUri.lastIndexOf('/')+1, imageUri.length());
                String fileNameWithoutExtension = fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf('.'));
                return fileNameWithoutExtension;
            }
        };

        String pathCache = Globais.getCacheDirImageLazyLoad(mContext); //returns StorageUtils.getCacheDirectory(context, false).getAbsolutePath() + "/lazyload";
        File f  = new File(pathCache);
        if (!f.exists())
            f.mkdirs();

        DiskCache diskCache = new UnlimitedDiskCache(f, null, fileNameGenerator);
        config.diskCache(diskCache);

        config.diskCacheFileNameGenerator(fileNameGenerator);

        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config.build());
```

Problem that after I started using the component that uses the picasso, began to double the cache, ALL images that use the Universal Image Loader, also appear in Picasso's cache.

How can I fix this ???

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Picasso doesn't have a disk cache. The HTTP client does. Are you using OkHttp? Are you using the same OkHttp cache for UIL and Picasso?

Comment: had not looked at the okhttp, I set up the cache to make okhttp was just looking at the Picasso library ..Tks :)